# pygame drawing items in inverse direction

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.6

The question is:

I'm trying to make platform generator for my pygame project but the problem is when I create platforms the positioning in the pygame is inverse how could I solve that problem?

The code in my settings.py

```
#Platform Generator
#Platforms(x, y, w, h)
PLATFORMS_LIST = []

for i in range(WIDTH):
    MAX_HEIGHT = random.randint(100, 120)
    PLATFORMS_LIST.append((i * 20, 300, 20, MAX_HEIGHT))
```

The code in sprites.py

```
class Platforms(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

[image: Output of code]

But I want the inverse of that green platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the maximum height is 120, then you have to shift the items by the difference `120-MAX_HEIGHT` to the bottom:

```py
MAX_HEIGHT = random.randint(100, 120)
# PLATFORMS_LIST.append((i * 20, 300, 20, MAX_HEIGHT))
PLATFORMS_LIST.append((i * 20, 300+120-MAX_HEIGHT, 20, MAX_HEIGHT))
```